# Compiler aid in base's assignment operator from derived

Tags: c++, operators, variable-assignment

Let say I have following classes

```
class Base
{
    // default CTOR
    // default Copy Assignment
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() 
        // Calls base constructor 
    {
        // implementation
    }

    Dervied& operator=(const Dervied& other)
    {
        A::operator = (other); // Why can't compiler offer this by default

        // implementation
    } 
};
```

I am curious to know why can't compiler offer calling base's assignment operator during derived assignment by default, why we need to explicitly call it.
Am I overlooking some case where this (calling A::operator = (other) ) would not be required.

For constructors compiler have this consideration (i.e. calling base's constructor during derived construction).

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for? All of that is just provided by default already, if you refrain to provide your own implementation.

Comment: i think you could use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration i.e.: using Base::operator=;

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious to know why can't compiler offer calling base's assignment operator during derived assignment by default

As soon you're going to provide your own implementation, the compiler is out of guessing what you actually want to achieve.

While calling `A::operator = (other)` looks like a reasonable default operation, you still might implement something different. The compiler cannot know, and won't restrict you, or going into your way doing so.

> why we need to explicitly call it. Am I overlooking some case where this (calling A::operator = (other) ) would not be required.

Just be creative, I could imagine cases where you actually want to override this behavior.

Comment: My point is, providing implementation for derived mandates developer to specify implementation for base. Isn't developer forgetting to call base's implementation poses a greater risk then few creative scenarios. Compiler can check if some base implementation is being called then don't inject default call (similar in a way base's constructor calling behaves)